# Dynamically read bash function name from inside bash function

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Say I have this:

```
foo(){
   install_ores_gitflow;
   command foo "$@"
}
```

what I want to do, is dynamically grab the function name, something like this:

```
foo(){
   install_ores_gitflow;
   command "$0" "$@"
}
```

where "$0" would evaluate to "foo"
is this possible somehow, I am looking for something reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the FUNCNAME shell variable? `man bash`:

> FUNCNAME
>
> An array variable containing the names of all shell functions currently in the execution call stack.  The element with
>   index 0 is the name of any  currently-executing  shell  function.

Comment: How to use it given the OP? can you show an example?

Comment: `foo() { command "$FUNCNAME" "$@"; }`

Comment: what a minute, is $FUNCNAME an array or just a string? how do I access just the first element of the array?

Comment: ` Referencing  an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing the array with a subscript of 0. ` (also from `man bash`)

Comment: Ahh that is cool, but if I wanted to be explicit, it would be this right `"${FUNCNAME[0]}"`, is there a way to do it shorter with `"$FUNCNAME[0]"`?